# Filter on sequential condition till another condition is met

Tags: r, filter, dplyr, time-series

How do I create a filter to meet two conditions:

1. Remove all rows where the value drops to greater than 80% of the day before.
2. Keep removing the rows following the drop till the value rises again over 50

```
data <- tibble(date = seq.Date(as.Date("2021-01-01"),as.Date("2021-01-01")+14,1),
       value = c(89,86,87,76,10,90,92,83,12,15,23,51,32, 88, 92)
       ) %>% 
  mutate(diff = (value-lag(value, default = first(value)))/lag(value, default = first(value)))
```

final output should be:

```
  date       value    diff
   <date>     <dbl>   <dbl>
 1 2021-01-01    89  0     
 2 2021-01-02    86 -0.0337
 3 2021-01-03    87  0.0116
 4 2021-01-04    76 -0.126 
 5 2021-01-06    90  8     
 6 2021-01-07    92  0.0222
 7 2021-01-08    83 -0.0978
 8 2021-01-12    51  1.22  
 9 2021-01-13    32 -0.373 
10 2021-01-14    88  1.75  
11 2021-01-15    92  0.0455
```

Comment: Its an unwanted column that I will end up deleting in the final output

Comment: One more thing! what'd be your expected outcome, if say consecutive values are 100, 5 (95% decrease), 10 (100% increase), 15 (50% increase), 16.5 (10% increase), 33 (200% increase).

Comment: Only 100 would remain till the values go up over 50 again so a sequence of `c(100,5,10,15,16.5,33,51,40)` would only have `c(100,  51, 40)`

Comment: Actually even though the answer below works, it doesn't generalise well at all, especially if you're starting with values less than 50. I abandoned the thought process and used a new criteria for the task that needs to be done within the shinyapp. I think it may have been a flawed thought process to begin with :)

Comment: Once more I'll bother you, (actually I found this one interesting as well as challenging) what'd be desired output for `A = c(102,100,50,60,20,100,5,10, 15,1,33,50,53)` as values drop here two times by 80% and rise only once?

Comment: output should be `c(102,100,50,60,20,100,53)` . You dont filter out any values till you get a drop greater than 80% and then you continue to filter out till the value goes over 50 again. If you want another example, this is where the below answer didnt work very well where `A = c(43,47,102,100,50,60,20,100,5,10, 15,1,33,50,53)` in which case the output should be `c(43, 47,102,100,50,60,20,100,53)` as there is no dropping condition met for the first 2 elements 43 and 47.

Comment: The second drop between  `15` and `1` is irrelevant because now you are filtering on the second condition `<= 50` as the first condition happened between `100` and `5`. Its only after you get to `53` the first condition of `diff < -0.8` gets activated again.

Comment: Thanks for clarification. I'll work it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a approach using `data.table::rleid`

```r
library(dplyr)

data <- tibble(
  date = seq.Date(as.Date("2021-01-01"), as.Date("2021-01-01") + 14, 1),
  value = c(43,47,87,76,10,90,92,83,12,15,23,51,32, 88, 92)
)

data %>%
  mutate(diff = (value - lag(value, default = first(value))) /
      lag(value, default = first(value))) %>%
  mutate(to_remove = diff <= -.8) %>%
  # calculate the index of removing to group rows after first removing rows
  mutate(group_remove = data.table::rleid(to_remove)) %>%
  # for those groups as long as no line reach value 50
  # to_continue_remove variable is assign FALSE
  group_by(group_remove) %>%
  mutate(to_continue_remove = (group_remove > 1) & !to_remove &
      cumsum(value >= 50) == 0) %>%
  # filter remove rows for 1st condition diff < 80%
  filter(!to_remove) %>%
  # continue filter rows after removed rows that haven't reach 50 yet
  filter(!to_continue_remove)

#> # A tibble: 11 x 6
#> # Groups:   group_remove [3]
#>    date       value    diff to_remove group_remove to_continue_remove
#>    <date>     <dbl>   <dbl> <lgl>            <int> <lgl>             
#>  1 2021-01-01    43  0      FALSE                1 FALSE             
#>  2 2021-01-02    47  0.0930 FALSE                1 FALSE             
#>  3 2021-01-03    87  0.851  FALSE                1 FALSE             
#>  4 2021-01-04    76 -0.126  FALSE                1 FALSE             
#>  5 2021-01-06    90  8      FALSE                3 FALSE             
#>  6 2021-01-07    92  0.0222 FALSE                3 FALSE             
#>  7 2021-01-08    83 -0.0978 FALSE                3 FALSE             
#>  8 2021-01-12    51  1.22   FALSE                5 FALSE             
#>  9 2021-01-13    32 -0.373  FALSE                5 FALSE             
#> 10 2021-01-14    88  1.75   FALSE                5 FALSE             
#> 11 2021-01-15    92  0.0455 FALSE                5 FALSE
```

<sup>Created on 2021-05-10 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>

***Updated: adjust the solution to not remove rows from first group if their starting value is below 50***

Comment: Just a note on this, this doesnt work if the first few elements are less than 50 before the dropping criteria is met.

Comment: May you share the sample of the case that it failed?

Comment: replace the Value column in the previous dataset with `c(43,47,87,76,10,90,92,83,12,15,23,51,32, 88, 92)`. The first two entries should not be excluded in the final output. After filtering the value column should have `c(43,47,87,76,90,92,83,51,32, 88, 92)`